# How to render Partial View in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to render partial view in my application and could not display the value. Here is what my View looks like.

My Main Index View

```
 <div id="RPPricingNameModel">
     @Html.Partial("RPPricingPlanNames")
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#RPPricingNameModel").load("/Home/GetPlanNameModel");    
</script>
```

Partial View

```
@model PlanNameModel     
<table style= "vertical-align:top; left:0px; top:0px; position:absolute; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:Green;  width:130px; text-align:left;">    
    <tr>
        <td style=" font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:Black;">            
            @Model.Header
           <div>            
                  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Header)               
           </div>   
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Here is the controller that returns the view.

```
public ActionResult GetPlanNameModel()
{
   PlanNameModel planNameModel = new PlanNameModel();
   planNameModel.Header = "Plans";
   //return View(planNameModel);
   return PartialView(planNameModel);   
}
```

Here is code for Model

```
public class RPPricingPlanNameModel
{
  public string Header { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to display the value in TD, it does not show anything.
Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is to use partialViews and not specifically load them dynamically with jquery, please take a look at my answer to this question, and it should probably solve your problem:

[MVC3 Partial Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663190/mvc3-partial-views/8663259#8663259)

All you have to do is Create a ViewModel for your index that contains all the objects that your partial view(s) need

Controller ActionMethod:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  PlanNameModel planNameModel = new PlanNameModel();
  planNameModel.Header = "Plans";
  ViewData.Model = new IndexVm{ PlanNameModel = planNameModel };
}
```

ViewModel:

```
   public class IndexVm
   {
     public PlanNameModel PlanNameModel { get; set; }
   }
```

Index View

```
@model IndexVm

@*Whatever index code you have*@

@Html.Partial("PlanPartial", Model.PlanNameModel)
```

Partial View

```
@model PlanNameModel

<div>@Model.Header</div>
```

Comment: I am little confused. Can you explain it more?

Comment: Hey i figured out this much so far from debugging. May be that will trigger something to resolve this. I put an alert in the .load function. It renders my Partial View and that time the model it empty. so the value will be null. Then the alert tells me that it running java script and getting the values by calling controller method. But after that it loads the page instead of rendering the partial view again with new model.values. Do you get the sequence? If i can render the partial view after the controller method then it work. Any ideas????

Comment: @VivekPatel I added more explanation to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I was doing the same after your previous post.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are missing the selector you are looking for in your jquery selector

you need to add:

```
<div id="RPPricingNameModel"></div>
```

to your DOM

also your **@m.Header** should be **@Model.Header**

and finally your javascript to load the partial view should not be **in** your partial view, it should be on the main view that you wanna load the partial view into

Comment: I tries this. Its not working for me. It is displaying the value "Header" instead of the actual value "Plans" that i assign to Model.Header.

Comment: Tried that as well. Moved the Javascript to main Index.cshtml and changed the m.Header to @Model.Header. Now getting null reference exepction.

Comment: what happens if you put a breakpoint in your GetPlanNameModel()? is it getting there?

Comment: Yes It is getting there. And i can see the model i return is not null.

Comment: update your question to reflect you latest changes, maybe we'll be able to spot the problem, because if you made these changes your model should not be null

Comment: I have just updated my question with the changes.I am trying different combinations to get the value as well. Please advice me if you think I am doing anything wrong. Thanks.!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

replace your index with:

```
<div id="RPPricingNameModel"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){$("#RPPricingNameModel").load("/Home/GetPlanNameModel");});
</script>
```

The null reference is caused by the initial call to your partial by

```
@Html.Partial("RPPricingPlanNames")
```

without the required model

Comment: Now I am getting '' as a result instead of any value. How can i remove that null reference error.

Comment: one more suggestion: replace load with get

Comment: Basically All i want to do it a load some texts from Database into my Page. I have different section on my page and i have divided them into different Partial Views. Now I want to load those Labels with the text from Database. I am trying to accomplish that using this technique but it seems like its not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the  `$("#RPPricingNameModel").load("/Home/GetPlanNameModel");` inside the document ready so that it will be executed only after the complete dom is loaded

```
$(function(){

 $("#RPPricingNameModel").load("/Home/GetPlanNameModel");

});
```

Comment: that's already covered by my answer, that doesn't seem to be the problem unfortunately

Comment: This seems pretty simple but somehow i cant get this thing to work. :(