# MVC 3 Combinging multiple controls in one sort control template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on some forms, and often I can reuse the same amount and combination of fields together, is it possible to group them all as a template and then call it from the page?

For example:
2 radio buttons with labels and 2 texboxes under.

How is it called so i can do a proper research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Partial View, its like a reusable component.

These links will elaborate more:

1. http://www.devcurry.com/2012/04/partial-views-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html
2. http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/2IKW160912-Partial-View-in-Asp.net-MVC3-Razor.html
3. [MVC3 Partial Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663190/mvc3-partial-views)

Answer (score 1):

Create a Partial View and keep your markup which you want to reuse in that. You can use these Partial views in other views as needed then.

You can use the Html.Partial helper method to call the partial views in other views.

```
@Html.Partial("RecentItems")
```

You can also pass some model to your partial view as well

```
@Html.Partial("RecentItems", Model.RecentItems)
```

Assuming Your partial view is strongly typed to a class which is of the same type as the type of `Model.RecentItems`, of the caller  view.